# If function execute more than x seconds php

Tags: php, time, set, limit, get-headers

In my script i use this function:

```
function url_exists($url) {
 if ((strpos($url, "http")) === false) $url = "http://" . $url;
 if (is_array(@get_headers($url)))
      return true;
 else
      return false;
}
```

How can i set the time limit of execute function @get_headers? I need function like set_time_limit() by works for one function, not for whole script.

Comment: Do you have the `curl` extension installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `get_headers()` doesn't supports a timeout or a context param. Try:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', YOUR_VALUE_IN_SECONDS);
```

This will set the default timeout to a value of your choice. Don't forget to reset the timeout after the operation has finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it with [ini setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) or by creating default context values for streams:

```
stream_context_set_default(array(
    'http' => array('timeout' => 10) // in seconds
));
```